# Getting a copy of all e-mails passing through postfix?

Tags: email, postfix, stress-testing

I'm changing postfix installations from one installed years ago by people who are no longer here on an operating system which is no longer supported, and I'd like to get a sampling of real data from the existing postfix installation to test the new installation.

So, is there a way to get a copy of *all* e-mails going through a postfix saved somewhere?

Please note that most stress test tools I found out there are not adequate for our needs, because what most needs testing is how anti-spam and anti-virus are reacting, and the stress testers I found generate random data instead of using real samples.

Answer (score 2):

[Previously on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/755853/postfix-send-a-copy-of-every-email-to-a-given-email-address)

Comment: Not really what I want, but I'll keep it in mind. In particular, it won't send e-mail that is being held or rejected, which are the ones most important to me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes   you can copy all mail  i can give now example

If     you instal  in old server   postfix  in /home/vmail ..   for example   you have domains 
  domain1.com , domain2.com , domain3.com
You can copy all domains with rsync  in new server   with root. After that   you need to change grup  like that. In new server  on domain /home/vmail/domain1.com   you have to  make this  chown  vmail:vmail /home/vmail/domain1.com -Rf  . You need laste command becouse only vmail have permition to write and read  this folder . If  root is owner on this folder   you cant  make anything.

Comment: Sorry, this isn't what I'm looking for. I have an SMTP _relay_, and I want a copy of all mail going _through_ it.